# Use $resource in external function with angularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Excuse me, i'm starter with angularJS, i just want to knw if it's possible to use a `$resource` in a simple jquery function without controllers

Comment: No, Angular is not a jQuery add-on.

Comment: See the answers in this question, they might help you start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1